# How can I calculate the percentage score from test results using tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Rather than calculate each individuals score, I want to calculate the percentage of individuals who answered the question correctly. Below is the tibble containing the data, the columns are the candidates, a-r, and the rows are the questions. The data points are the answers given, and the column on the right, named 'correct', shows the correct answer.

```
A tibble: 20 x 19
   question   a     b     c     d     e     g     h     i     j     k     l     m     n     o     p     q     r     correct
   <chr>         <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>  
 1 001        3     3     3     0     4     0     1     4     4     0     2     3     2     0     3     0     3     1      
 2 002        2     4     2     3     4     NA    4     2     2     2     4     2     4     3     2     2     3     2      
 3 003        2     2     2     3     4     2     2     4     4     1     4     3     3     2     4     1     3     2      
 4 005        2     3     1     3     4     NA    2     4     4     2     4     1     4     2     4     2     2     2      
 5 006        3     1     2     3     3     NA    2     3     4     2     3     3     3     3     3     NA    3     3      
 6 008        3     3     3     3     3     1     1     3     3     1     3     3     3     3     3     1     3     3      
 7 010        4     5     4     3     4     4     4     4     4     3     4     4     5     4     4     3     4     4      
 8 011        3     3     5     3     3     3     3     3     5     4     5     4     4     3     3     2     5     5      
 9 013        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      
10 014        0     0     0     2     0     1     0     0     0     0     2     0     2     0     0     0     0     0      
11 016        3     3     0     0     4     1     1     4     4     2     3     3     3     3     1     0     3     0      
12 017        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      
13 019        0     1     0     2     1     1     0     1     0     1     2     2     2     1     0     1     1     0      
14 020        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     3     0     0     0     0     0     0      
15 039        0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      
16 041        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0      
17 045        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      
18 047        0     0     0     0     0     NA    0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      
19 049        3     3     3     3     4     NA    2     4     x     2     4     3     5     3     1     1     3     3      
20 050        0     3     3     0     1     NA    0     3     3     0     x     0     0     0     0     0     3     1
```

I would like to generate a column 'percentage' that gives the proportion of correct answers for each question. I suspect I have to do loops or row-wise operations, but I'm so far out of my depth with that, I just can't figure out how to compare factors. I've tried `mutate()`, `if_else()`, `group_by()` and much more but have not managed to get close to an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Jim! It would be a very kind of you if you provide some sample or reproducible data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data.frame is called `data` you may try

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% rowwise() %>%
    mutate(percentage = sum(c_across(a:r) == correct) / length(c_across(a:r)))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly to do exactly what I needed, and I learnt about c_across() in the bargain! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution using a loop:

```
#Code
#First select the range of individuals a to r
index <- 2:18
#Create empty var to save results
df$Count <- NA
df$Prop <- NA
#Apply function
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1])
{
  x <- df[i,index]
  count <- length(which(x==df$correct[i]))
  percentage <- count/dim(x)[2]
  #Assign
  df$Count[i] <- count
  df$Prop[i] <- percentage
}
```

Output:

```
   question a b c d e  g h i  j k  l m n o p  q r correct Count       Prop
1         1 3 3 3 0 4  0 1 4  4 0  2 3 2 0 3  0 3       1     1 0.05882353
2         2 2 4 2 3 4 NA 4 2  2 2  4 2 4 3 2  2 3       2     8 0.47058824
3         3 2 2 2 3 4  2 2 4  4 1  4 3 3 2 4  1 3       2     6 0.35294118
4         5 2 3 1 3 4 NA 2 4  4 2  4 1 4 2 4  2 2       2     6 0.35294118
5         6 3 1 2 3 3 NA 2 3  4 2  3 3 3 3 3 NA 3       3    10 0.58823529
6         8 3 3 3 3 3  1 1 3  3 1  3 3 3 3 3  1 3       3    13 0.76470588
7        10 4 5 4 3 4  4 4 4  4 3  4 4 5 4 4  3 4       4    12 0.70588235
8        11 3 3 5 3 3  3 3 3  5 4  5 4 4 3 3  2 5       5     4 0.23529412
9        13 0 0 0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1  1 0 0 0 0  0 0       0    14 0.82352941
10       14 0 0 0 2 0  1 0 0  0 0  2 0 2 0 0  0 0       0    13 0.76470588
11       16 3 3 0 0 4  1 1 4  4 2  3 3 3 3 1  0 3       0     3 0.17647059
12       17 0 0 0 0 0  1 0 0  0 0  1 0 0 0 0  0 0       0    15 0.88235294
13       19 0 1 0 2 1  1 0 1  0 1  2 2 2 1 0  1 1       0     5 0.29411765
14       20 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0  1 3 0 0 0  0 0       0    15 0.88235294
15       39 0 0 0 0 1  1 0 0  0 0  1 0 0 0 0  0 0       0    14 0.82352941
16       41 0 0 0 0 0  1 0 0  0 0  1 0 0 0 0  1 0       0    14 0.82352941
17       45 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0       0    17 1.00000000
18       47 0 0 0 0 0 NA 0 0  0 0  1 0 0 0 0  0 0       0    15 0.88235294
19       49 3 3 3 3 4 NA 2 4 NA 2  4 3 5 3 1  1 3       3     7 0.41176471
20       50 0 3 3 0 1 NA 0 3  3 0 NA 0 0 0 0  0 3       1     1 0.05882353
```

You had some `x` in answers so I have replaced by `NA` in order to make the loop works.